# WrkTaskIP.aspx Task Page Change Redirect URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a workflow with customised task forms so clicking on a workflow task opens up the task page WrkTaskIP.aspx with an InfoPath form hosted within it.

The task form has a submit button which submits to the hosting environment to complete the task and the page by default will then redirect to the WrkStat.aspx page to display the status of the workflow after submitting the task.

However I would like to be able to change this default redirection to another URL which I would normally do by modifying the &Source parameter in the URL however this time I have no control over this.

Is there any way to achieve the redirection to another URL in this situation?

(That does not involve a global change to a _layout form)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by having a task form change view to a "Task Completed" screen on submit which then includes a link to the place they should be redirected to.

Since I already have found a way to get hyperlinks to open in the same window, it nearly has the same effect as what I was originally after.

The customers were actually happy with this because it confirmed to the user that they had completed the task rather than just redirecting after clicking submit.